# Definitive source(s) for the difference between Silverlight and WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight, compatibility

Does anyone know of a definitive guide or guides that tells us the differences between WPF and Silverlight.  I know that Silverlight, for example, doesn’t have all the controls and all the namespaces that WPF has.  Is there a source which tells me exactly what controls and namespaces are absent in Silverlight?

There are other things that I know off the top of my head, like only allowing asynchronous communications using basic http binding.  Also, Silverlgiht doesn’t have all of the type converters out of the box.

Anyone else have interesting experiences with the nuances or know of sources that explain them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[XAML Processing Differences Between Silverlight and WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917841(VS.95).aspx)

[WPF Compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903925(VS.95).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Two more useful resources -

> Guidance on Differences Between WPF
>   and Silverlight:
>   http://wpfslguidance.codeplex.com/
>
> Contrasting Silverlight and WPF:
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921107(v=pandp.20).aspx