# Silverlight 4 and WPF Compatibility

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

So if I created a Silverlight app, can I take the markup + code and put it in a WPF app?  I was just curious if we decide to use Silverlight, whether I could also take advantage of WPF Windows clients too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Definitive source(s) for the difference between Silverlight and WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/598703/definitive-sources-for-the-difference-between-silverlight-and-wpf)

Comment: This question has been asked in several various ways, searching in site:stackoverflow.com for keywords such as silverlight, WPF, differences, compatiblity etc will find you plenty of answers on this subject already.

Comment: But I want to know the process too for setting up a silverlight app to work in a WPF environment as well..  so I disagree, I think mine is a little different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This MSDN article may be a good reference as to where SL4 and WPF4 diverge:

[WPF Compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903925.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You could always make your Silverlight application run Out-Of-Browser, just keep in mind you have a security sandbox which you dont have with WPF. Also Silverlight would be able to run on Macintosh without use of Mono which could be a benefit.